# Silverstripe: Remove Viewer Groups Tab

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to remove the 'ViewerGroups' tab from the back end of the CMS. I've tried:

```
$fields->removeByName("Root.ViewerGroups");
```

and

```
$fields->removeByName("ViewerGroups");
```

but neither seem to be working. Does anyone know how I can remove this tab?

Comment: Where does the `ViewerGroup` tab appear in the CMS?

Answer (score 3):

You need to access it in the existing tab object:

```
$fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Settings', 'ViewerGroups');
```